# C# Calculator Text Input Validation

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, validation

I am currently writing a calculator application. One part of this application is a Simple Calculator that works like the calculator in windows (using windows 8). It can parse the numbers entered in the textbox. However, if the user does not enter in the correct form such as 5 * * 5 it will give an error. I want it to check the character entered before to see if its an operator and if it is, replace it such as 5 * / 5 to become 5 / 5 as the user is typing. Also it will need to check the parenthesis are in the correct order such as () or () not )(. The other thing it will need to check is that the number being entered only has one decimal point. For example, 4.38585 + 5.32948. I have already limited key entries to only numbers and operators. I have checked this for some time now, but have not seen any solutions.

Comment: show us some code please.

Comment: Show some of your code

Comment: it seems you are being a bit lazy as for asking us to do your work. you know what you need and just asking us... if you'll put a char for the operation and change it as you get new operation char then you can handle 5 * / 5 string

Comment: Ahh the problem is quite clear, you have not attempted to write any code... How on earth are you going to pass your course?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to allow the user to enter an expression and then make him press a "calculate" button, then you should not validate things on the fly. Let the user make mistakes, since he will anyway. The user will want to go back and edit the text that he's entered. Your editing rules will make that difficult or impossible. Or worse, inconsistent.

For example, say that the user enters `4.35*7.29`.

Then he realizes that he wanted to divide. But your editing rules won't let him delete the `*` because that would make for an invalid number. And he can't enter the `/` first and then delete, because doing so would give `/*` or `*/`, both of which are invalid. Are you going to allow the temporary invalid expression when editing, but not allow it when the user is typing? That would be inconsistent, and wouldn't prevent your evaluator from having to do the error checking again and notify the user.

Limit keystrokes to numbers and operators if you like, but don't try to validate the form of what the user inputs. Let him type **)9(// if he wants. Handle the error when you're parsing--AFTER the user has pressed the calculate button.

Now, if your application works like Windows Calculator in that it keeps a running total as the user enters values and operators, that's a different matter. But what you're talking about would just be frustrating. I certainly wouldn't want to use it.